# How to select first and last elements via XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here is a sample XML, and I am trying to figure out how to select first node value and exit the loop. If I use following XSLT tag

```
<xsl:value-of select="fruits/fruit"/>
```

it returns "apple mango banana" but expected result should be "apple"

```
<fruits>
  <fruit>apple</fruit>
  <fruit>mango</fruit>
  <fruit>banana</fruit>
</fruits>
```

I'd also like to select the last `fruit` without knowing how many `fruit` exist a priori.  So, for the above example, I'd like to return "banana" without knowing that there are 3 `fruit` elements.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### First

You can select the value of the first `fruit` (of the root `fruits` element) via `fruit[1]`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(/fruits/fruit)[1]"/>
```

will return `"apple"` as requested.

**Important:** For an explanation of the difference between `(/fruits/fruit)[1]` and `/fruits/fruit[1]`, see [How to select first element via XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38527329/290085)

---

### Last

You can select the value of the last `fruit` via `fruit[last()]`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(/fruits/fruit)[last()]"/>
```

will return `"banana"`  as requested without knowing how many fruits exist a priori.

See also the explanation regarding the use of `()` given for the `first()` case.

Comment: is it correct to say "loop" here? I don't think `xsl:value-of` works as a loop. Have read it somewhere. Just asking for clarification.

Comment: Right, OP asked specifically about a loop, but in XSLT and XPath it's better to think in declarative concepts such as matching than in procedural concepts such as looping.

Comment: Yes, it may not be called as loop.I just started learning XSLT so probably using wrong terminology...BTW thanks for correcting

Comment: Another Question, how do i find out the value of last node if i don't know how many nodes exist??

Comment: @user3767641: You can use `last()`.  Answer updated to show how.