# How to select first element via XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following HTML structure

```
<div class="carousel">
  <ul class ="carousel-view">
    <li>
      <figure>
        <a id="one"/>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure>
        <a id="two"/>
      </figure>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I use XPath to access the first `a` element? Notice there are multiple `a` elements inside the list.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Any of these XPath expressions will select the first `a` element:

- `(//a)[1]` selects first `a` in the whole document.
- `(/div/ul/li/figure/a)[1]` selects first `a` with shown heritage.
- `(//div[@class='carousel']/ul/li/figure/a)[1]` restricts heritage.
- `(//div[@class='carousel']//a)[1]` abstracts away some heritage.

Choose depending upon the context of your shown XML in your actual document and whether you wish to restrict the `a` elements to only those under certain other elements.

### Common Mistake

Note that `//a[1]` actually selects ***multiple*** `a` elements:

```
<a id="one"/>
<a id="two"/>
```

because `//a[1]` means *select the `a` elements that are the first child of its parent*.

**You must use parentheses `(//a)[1]` to select**

```
<a id="one"/>
```

**alone as the first `a` in the document.**

Answer (score 2):

try this `xpath` :-

```
(//li/descendant::a)[1]
```