# Get first element Xpath

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath, puppeteer

I have a HTML like this :

```
<ol class="list">
   <li class="list-item " id="37647629">
      <!---->
      <div>
         <!---->
         <div>
            <!---->
            <book class="book">
              <div class="title">
                 someText
              </div>    
              <div class="year">
                 2022
              </div>               
            </book>
         </div>
         <!---->         
      </div>
      <!---->
   </li>
   <li class="list-item " id="37647778">
      <!---->
      <div>
         <!---->
         <div>
            <!---->
            <book class="book">
              <div class="title">
                 someOtherText
              </div>    
              <div class="year">
                 2014
              </div>            
            </book>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
   </li>   
</ol>
```

I want to get the first book title and year, directly with two xPath expression.
I tried :

```
$x('//book') => Ok, get the two books list

$x('//book[0]') => Empty list    

$x('//book[0]/div[@class="title"]') => Nothing
```

Seems I have to do this :

`$x('//book')[0]`

and then process title, but why I can't do this just with Xpath and directly access the first title with a Xpath expression ?

Comment: what is wrong with `(//book)[1]` as the xpath?

Comment: Nothing, I was just a little tired and don’t see that it could be a xpath expression itself, I thing //book was xpath and [1] was JavaScript after that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the first book title

```xml
"(//book)[1]//div[@class='title']"
```

And this gives the first book year

```xml
"(//book)[1]//div[@class='year']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing that XPath indexing starts at `1`; JavaScript indexing starts at `0`.

- `$x('//book')` selects all `book` elements in the document.
- `$x('//book[0]')` selects nothing because XPath indexing starts at `1`.  (It also signifies to select all `book` elements that are the first among siblings — *not* necessarily the same as the first of all `book` elements in the document.)

  - `$x('//book')[0]` would select the first `book` element because JavaScript indexing starts at `0`.
  - `$x('(//book)[1]')` would select the first `book` element because XPath indexing starts at `1`.

To select the first `div` with `class` of `'title'`, all in XPath:

```
$x('(//div[@class="title"])[1]')
```

or, using JavaScript to index:

```
$x('(//div[@class="title"])')[0]
```

To return just the string value without the leading/trailing whitespace, wrap in `normalize-space()`:

```
$x('normalize-space((//div[@class="title"])[1])')
```

Note that `normalize-space()` will also consolidate internal whitespace, but that is of no consequence with this example.

### See also

- [How to select first element via XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38527329/290085) (And be sure not to miss the explanation of the difference between `//book[1]` and `(//book)[1]` — they are *not* the same.)