# Why does XPath return more elements than I expect?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, domxpath

Why does `//div["someClass"]/p[1]` also return `p`-tags not wrapped in the requested div-element using XPath? Only `//*/div["someClass"]/p[1]` returns the expected result with the example HTML:

```html
<p>Foo</p>

<div class="someClass">
    <p>Bar</p>
</div>
```

- `//div["someClass"]/p[1]` also returns the first Foo p-tag.
- `//*/div["someClass"]/p[1]` only returns the expected Bar.

If it matters: I use PHP's `DOMXPath`.

Comment: That looks like a buggy xpath parser to me. The xpath parsers in both python's `lxml` module and in `xmllint` both return the expected result (`<p>Bar</p>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. XPath is only defined over [*well-formed* XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085), and your posted example is not well-formed because it has multiple roots.  Perhaps your actual XML/HTML has a single root and other unposted markup; then there's also another consideration...
2. See [How to select the first element via XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38527329/290085) to avoid a common gotcha when trying to select the first element in XPath:

   `//x[1]` means to select the `x` elements that are the first child of its parent, not the first `x` in the document; `(//x)[1]` will select the first `x` element in the document.