# XPath for last selected element via browser console?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I have an XPath:

```xpath
$x(("//div[@class='ag-header-row']"))[1]
```

that gives me an array of `div`s.
The `[1]` at the end is necessary because there are other rows with this class.

I know about `[last()]` but not sure where to insert it.

How do I modify the XPath to select the last `div`?

Here is screenshot of the elements[image]

Comment: Try `("//div[@class='ag-header-row']")[count("//div[@class='ag-header-row']")]`

Comment: Thanks for responding @JaSON I tried that in Google console but got "count is not defined" error. I was hoping to use [last()] because I also want to use [first()]

Comment: There is no such operator in XPath as `first`. Try `"(//div[@class='ag-header-row'])[last()]"`

Comment: If you look at my path that works and returns an array of divs there is a [1] at the end. That [1] is necessary to get the array. Your suggestion doesn't work because it doesn't have the [1]. I am not sure how to add [last()]

Comment: Your `[1]` doesn't looks like a part of XPath. I suggested you an XPath-solution. Share more details about your problem - it might be related to programming language

Comment: @JaSON: Right, as I already [mentioned in my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63635203/290085), the `[1]` is being applied in the context of JavaScript (in a browser console), not XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Your invocation of an XPath expression,

```
$x(("//div[@class='ag-header-row']"))[1]
```

means to select all `div` element with the given `class` attribute value, and, in JavaScript, *outside of XPath* take the **second** one (because JavaScript arrays start at 0, not 1 like XPath's).

You cannot replace the `[1]` with `[last()]` because there `last()` is an XPath function, not a JavaScript function.

If you want the last such `div` move `[last()]` into the XPath:

```
$x("(//div[@class='ag-header-row'])[last()]")
```

### See also:

- [How to select first and last elements via XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36415455/290085)
- [XPath to match @class value and element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19503721/290085)

  (See idiom for selecting based on a class attribute value being one among multiple listed classes.)

Comment: The [1] is necessary to select the correct row. The row I am interested in is the 2nd row of that class. I then want the last element in that row

Comment: Create a [mcve] using a simplified example of HTML or XML ***as text, never as an image*** to convey your requirements -- your prose description is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by incorporating reference to parent element

```js
$x("//div[@class='ag-header-container']//div[@class='ag-header-row']/div[last()]")
```