# XPath to select value from namespaced XML using local-name()?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

How to extract the value of `/substance/text` and `/makers/text`?

I am expecting the result to be

1. Automation
2. Test Record

I have tried many things for example:

- `//*[local-name()='text/@value']`
- `//*[local-name()='substance']/text/text()`
- `//*[local-name()='name'][1]` 
  (This works for first name element but if I use similar for text it doesn't work.)
- `//*[local-name()='text/@value'][1]`
- `//*[local-name()='text'][1]`

```
<health xmlns="http://test.com/sample">
    <substance>
        <name>substance</name>
        <text value="Automation"/>
    </substance>
    <user>
        <reference value="User/111111122"/>
    </user>
    <reaction>
        <makers>
            <name>makers</name>
            <text value="Test Record"/>
        </makers>
    </reaction>
</health>
```

Comment: The examples of what you tried show that you're guessing, and you're not really understanding what any of these expressions mean. You need to do some reading to get a better grasp of the concepts! Clearly there's no element in your document whose name is 'text/@value' - that's not a legal name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[local-name()='text']/@value
```

will select all of the `value` attributes of all `text` elements in the document, regardless of namespaces.

Note that it is better to account for namespaces than to defeat them in this manner.  See [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)

---

### Not working?

The provided XPath does select both `@value` attributes. If you're only seeing one, it's likely because you're passing the result on to an XPath 1.0 function that expects a single value and is defined to select the first member of a node-set when passed multiple values. See [Why does XPath expression only select text of first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69840439/290085)

---

### Still not working?

Here are two options for selecting the values individually rather than collectively:

1. `(//*[local-name()='text']/@value)[1]`
   `(//*[local-name()='text']/@value)[2]`
2. `//*[local-name()='substance']/*[local-name()='text']/@value`
   `//*[local-name()='makers']/*[local-name()='text']/@value`

Comment: Thanks it worked for the first `/substance/text` and I need to extract the value from `/makers/text` as well. How we can give the parent node in start?

Comment: Actually I am storing each value into a variable and hence `//*[local-name()='text']/@value` returns  `Automation` and stored in variable so now I have to get the second value somehow. Is there a way to pass the parent node in this expression?

Comment: Some how both above options are not working. Option 2 didn't work at all while for option 1 when I changed the array to Option 1: `(//*[local-name()='text']/@value)[1] and (//*[local-name()='text']/@value)[2]` it worked for [1] but not for [2].

Comment: See updated answer.  If the shown options  are still not working for you, I suspect there's a difference between your posted and actual XML or an issue in how you're using the results returned by the XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working fine I had one mistake in my code so once I corrected it started working